# The go-compiler reports variable declared but not used when using pointers

Tags: go

I have a snippet of code that i am unable to understand why the go compiler is reporting that a variable is declared but not used:

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    var StringSlice []*string
    
    MyStr0 := "Zero"
    StringSlice = append(StringSlice, &MyStr0)
    MyStr1 := "One"
    StringSlice = append(StringSlice, &MyStr1)
    MyStr2 := "Two"
    StringSlice = append(StringSlice, &MyStr2)

    var StrPtr *string
    for i, Value := range StringSlice {
        fmt.Println(Value)
        if i == 1 {
            StrPtr = Value
        }
    } // END for
```

With the Printf statement commented out, the go compiler claims »./prog.go:15:6: StrPtr declared but not used« - see the example in the go-playground at: https://go.dev/play/p/J3p4NDR6fBm
When the Printf is commented out, everything is fine and there's even the correct string-pointer stored in StrPtr…
Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: Where is the Printf statement that you mention? I cannot see it in the code you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using `StrPtr`. You are reassigning it, but it is never read. If you add that to a Printf statement the error will go away.

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    var StringSlice []*string

    MyStr0 := "Zero"
    StringSlice = append(StringSlice, &MyStr0)
    MyStr1 := "One"
    StringSlice = append(StringSlice, &MyStr1)
    MyStr2 := "Two"
    StringSlice = append(StringSlice, &MyStr2)

    var StrPtr *string
    for i, Value := range StringSlice {
        fmt.Println(Value)
        if i == 1 {
            StrPtr = Value
            fmt.Println(StrPtr) // <--- add this
        }
    } // END for
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
I didn't realize that a variable must be read in order to be "used" by the Go compiler, but that actually does make sense.